Running unpacked chrome extensions through the manifest V2 deprecation
I will be showing several chrome extensions in an art show starting in January 2025. They were all developed in 2017 using manifest V2 and will be installed as unpacked extensions in developer mode.

Will these stop working at some point as manifest V2 is deprecated or does that only affect extensions installed via the Chrome Web Store?
Is there a way I can have these extensions continue to work without having to migrate them to manifest V3? For example, by running an older version of Chrome?

Thanks

If a future version of Chrome disables MV2 extensions by default, you can re-allow it by enabling this flag that was added in Chrome 133:

chrome://flags/#allow-legacy-mv2-extensions

Its description says this flag is temporary, just like most of the flags, and will be removed when support for the enterprise policy is removed (planned in June 2025).
If an earlier version of Chrome disables MV2 by default, try setting these flags to disabled, which should disable the disabling of MV2:

chrome://flags/#extension-manifest-v2-deprecation-unsupported
chrome://flags/#extension-manifest-v2-deprecation-warning
chrome://flags/#extension-manifest-v2-deprecation-disabled

You can also set an enterprise policy: link.

If I use an earlier version of Chrome and set those three flags to disabled, can I run my chrome extensions indefinitely on MV2 assuming I don't update Chrome?

That's how it should work, yes.

Thanks! One more question. When you say earlier and future versions of Chrome, does this mean earlier than Chrome 133 and after Chrome 133 respectively?
As an example, I'm currently running Version 131.0.6778.205 (Official Build) (arm64) on my computer. If I pin this version I should be able to apply those latter three flags and continue to run my MV2 extensions without issue?

Flags take the precedence regardless of the defaults.
